# MongoDB\Driver php How to make inner join with filter in the first collection

Tags: php, mongodb

I need to make a join between two collections at the same time i need to execute filter for the first collection , exemple :

```
... // code inside my classe 
$this->MDBManager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb:// xxxxx: xxxxx @" . $this->host);
$filter = array ("date", array('$gte' =>str_replace("-","/", "2019-10-5") , '$lte' => str_replace("-","/",  2019-10-15)))
$this->MDBQuery = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filters, $options);
$this->results = $this->MDBManager->executeQuery("mydb.colllection1", $this->MDBQuery);
```

so this is my first collection and i need to join the soconde collection id to matche the same value of productEnsembleId attribute in collection 1.

The join request need to be in only  one request .

Thnak you so much for your help .

For more details :

exemple collection 1 :

```
{
  "_id": "5db8683c877c34001559f192",
  "id": "1BuVJCLGIUIcDXfBQVlpzccAP6r2JRQPGL4wHTEfPildnnWU5gUh8oymfJM2a6wOW117sTbzWJGKLNaRCZ7uMNHA2CnBjT4PeM44B9QaNYMZfg1BiiBa5JYBRLxMLxFTOY88PDFm4U4yDn9iPnljRnfeqpu9ZBl7fGS4tnnlmuz2ntlXb6cFFrFmQIo8EpDOwr5LLyaSrI67mLUya94WMUnDOojXpf4UAjcmMTayM4x9fmla_00001572366396",
  "userId": "DEXpMPBstW37YkixF5e6yPeVpkElumYN1nyw0rjjcPy6vf8mdUHXzIg8KMvy0KegxThD5LgKS6WnuhvPwbLqa3aoyhVgIOhk0huqvxmQ0ctBFMVZZyaPkADdGmWUFM10OhTo919uQOb4QgZLZjtDOnTkcmLUfB6uLFdfNmaXLRNaRs6w4GI9ZDwnuVWAgQ3uajWnUTigq1gXbKGcI4G4Es8cBKZsVQhxsKzOqLFGXDONbQEX_00000000000000",
  "productEnsembleId": "8FMOBUO8TArv0PcyQ2GSDhGPWRxMjMSLtCOcRV21G04yoCKq1i3POwPqEWwj6wJoeydY28thZMWmO4uP7Yha2xNMV1m0zmjfqtZgsKmTA1Qghku3I0rekTJ51cH2XlXan4zUV5hjjEolRWjREOR7N9DD9sCvoQF2kr3EhI553RYIdwgivRtYJYH4g6oqVv2nrob3KbrLwd95MbNnzwmCqGNM20q0zgF8HUJjCxIfphNyVcwO_00001571329166",
  "date": "2019/11/01",
  "status": "En cours"
}
```

exmple collextion 2 :

```
   {
  "_id": "5da8948e877c34001529a7f2",
  "id": "8FMOBUO8TArv0PcyQ2GSDhGPWRxMjMSLtCOcRV21G04yoCKq1i3POwPqEWwj6wJoeydY28thZMWmO4uP7Yha2xNMV1m0zmjfqtZgsKmTA1Qghku3I0rekTJ51cH2XlXan4zUV5hjjEolRWjREOR7N9DD9sCvoQF2kr3EhI553RYIdwgivRtYJYH4g6oqVv2nrob3KbrLwd95MbNnzwmCqGNM20q0zgF8HUJjCxIfphNyVcwO_00001571329166",
  "name": "ensemble 2",
  "image": "fjO9sb3FUmDFhgWn49v1Io5Oa5sdFyL7KZRVzsH0n06n7GtNqIPdFSfDT67BSIvfYSmdTh7IoYyize3SDX169cas4MWMwVWLsF989ZWy76ANsYS4tkLS5OYR1i2TrqXjP40WDCcWvr6OkQapgzuk4hAISx7Mwf6Wp2Z3krzjn72PrTXUDmG7nDrp7VKDrsonCVqkmGs7lAwocdEeghWs7NUVkMdIGMjWDVo8u3wlClzs2e5X_00001571329177",
  "produits": null
}
```

Comment: can you please provide at a minimum one document from each collection?

Comment: @barrypicker , thank you for you help i added exemples of documents

Comment: which field do you wish to join on?

Comment: @barrypicker , collection 1 in productEnsembleId , to collection 2 : id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So assuming you want the join results for one document in the first collection, here is a mongo shell query.

```
db.col1.aggregate([
  { $match: { "_id": "5db8683c877c34001559f192" } },
  { $lookup: {
      from: "col2",
      localField: "productEnsembleId",
      foreignField: "id",
      as: "col2_data"  
    }
  }
])
```

The results look like ...

```
{
    "_id" : "5db8683c877c34001559f192",
    "id" : "1BuVJCLGIUIcDXfBQVlpzccAP6r2JRQPGL4wHTEfPildnnWU5gUh8oymfJM2a6wOW117sTbzWJGKLNaRCZ7uMNHA2CnBjT4PeM44B9QaNYMZfg1BiiBa5JYBRLxMLxFTOY88PDFm4U4yDn9iPnljRnfeqpu9ZBl7fGS4tnnlmuz2ntlXb6cFFrFmQIo8EpDOwr5LLyaSrI67mLUya94WMUnDOojXpf4UAjcmMTayM4x9fmla_00001572366396",
    "userId" : "DEXpMPBstW37YkixF5e6yPeVpkElumYN1nyw0rjjcPy6vf8mdUHXzIg8KMvy0KegxThD5LgKS6WnuhvPwbLqa3aoyhVgIOhk0huqvxmQ0ctBFMVZZyaPkADdGmWUFM10OhTo919uQOb4QgZLZjtDOnTkcmLUfB6uLFdfNmaXLRNaRs6w4GI9ZDwnuVWAgQ3uajWnUTigq1gXbKGcI4G4Es8cBKZsVQhxsKzOqLFGXDONbQEX_00000000000000",
    "productEnsembleId" : "8FMOBUO8TArv0PcyQ2GSDhGPWRxMjMSLtCOcRV21G04yoCKq1i3POwPqEWwj6wJoeydY28thZMWmO4uP7Yha2xNMV1m0zmjfqtZgsKmTA1Qghku3I0rekTJ51cH2XlXan4zUV5hjjEolRWjREOR7N9DD9sCvoQF2kr3EhI553RYIdwgivRtYJYH4g6oqVv2nrob3KbrLwd95MbNnzwmCqGNM20q0zgF8HUJjCxIfphNyVcwO_00001571329166",
    "date" : "2019/11/01",
    "status" : "En cours",
    "col2_data" : [
        {
            "_id" : "5da8948e877c34001529a7f2",
            "id" : "8FMOBUO8TArv0PcyQ2GSDhGPWRxMjMSLtCOcRV21G04yoCKq1i3POwPqEWwj6wJoeydY28thZMWmO4uP7Yha2xNMV1m0zmjfqtZgsKmTA1Qghku3I0rekTJ51cH2XlXan4zUV5hjjEolRWjREOR7N9DD9sCvoQF2kr3EhI553RYIdwgivRtYJYH4g6oqVv2nrob3KbrLwd95MbNnzwmCqGNM20q0zgF8HUJjCxIfphNyVcwO_00001571329166",
            "name" : "ensemble 2",
            "image" : "fjO9sb3FUmDFhgWn49v1Io5Oa5sdFyL7KZRVzsH0n06n7GtNqIPdFSfDT67BSIvfYSmdTh7IoYyize3SDX169cas4MWMwVWLsF989ZWy76ANsYS4tkLS5OYR1i2TrqXjP40WDCcWvr6OkQapgzuk4hAISx7Mwf6Wp2Z3krzjn72PrTXUDmG7nDrp7VKDrsonCVqkmGs7lAwocdEeghWs7NUVkMdIGMjWDVo8u3wlClzs2e5X_00001571329177",
            "produits" : null
        }
    ]
}
```

which is a combination of collection 1 and collection 2.  If you want all records from collection 1 simply remove the $match criteria.

**Edit:  Include PHP version of same query above...**

To use this query in a PHP page see below.  This example assumes using the latest MongoDB driver and strategies including using PHP Composer...

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new MongoDB\Client('mongodb://johndoe:mypassword@localhost:27017');
$collection = $client->ensemble->col1;

$cursor = $collection->aggregate(
  array(
    array( '$match' => array( '_id' => '5db8683c877c34001559f192' ) ),
    array(
      '$lookup' => array(
      'from' => 'col2',
      'localField' => 'productEnsembleId',
      'foreignField' => 'id',
      'as' => 'col2_data'
      )   
    )   
  )
);

foreach($cursor as $document) {
  print_r($document);
}

?>
```

**PHP Results:**

```
MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument Object
(
    [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
        (
            [_id] => 5db8683c877c34001559f192
            [id] => 1BuVJCLGIUIcDXfBQVlpzccAP6r2JRQPGL4wHTEfPildnnWU5gUh8oymfJM2a6wOW117sTbzWJGKLNaRCZ7uMNHA2CnBjT4PeM44B9QaNYMZfg1BiiBa5JYBRLxMLxFTOY88PDFm4U4yDn9iPnljRnfeqpu9ZBl7fGS4tnnlmuz2ntlXb6cFFrFmQIo8EpDOwr5LLyaSrI67mLUya94WMUnDOojXpf4UAjcmMTayM4x9fmla_00001572366396
            [userId] => DEXpMPBstW37YkixF5e6yPeVpkElumYN1nyw0rjjcPy6vf8mdUHXzIg8KMvy0KegxThD5LgKS6WnuhvPwbLqa3aoyhVgIOhk0huqvxmQ0ctBFMVZZyaPkADdGmWUFM10OhTo919uQOb4QgZLZjtDOnTkcmLUfB6uLFdfNmaXLRNaRs6w4GI9ZDwnuVWAgQ3uajWnUTigq1gXbKGcI4G4Es8cBKZsVQhxsKzOqLFGXDONbQEX_00000000000000
            [productEnsembleId] => 8FMOBUO8TArv0PcyQ2GSDhGPWRxMjMSLtCOcRV21G04yoCKq1i3POwPqEWwj6wJoeydY28thZMWmO4uP7Yha2xNMV1m0zmjfqtZgsKmTA1Qghku3I0rekTJ51cH2XlXan4zUV5hjjEolRWjREOR7N9DD9sCvoQF2kr3EhI553RYIdwgivRtYJYH4g6oqVv2nrob3KbrLwd95MbNnzwmCqGNM20q0zgF8HUJjCxIfphNyVcwO_00001571329166
            [date] => 2019/11/01
            [status] => En cours
            [col2_data] => MongoDB\Model\BSONArray Object
                (
                    [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument Object
                                (
                                    [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
                                        (
                                            [_id] => 5da8948e877c34001529a7f2
                                            [id] => 8FMOBUO8TArv0PcyQ2GSDhGPWRxMjMSLtCOcRV21G04yoCKq1i3POwPqEWwj6wJoeydY28thZMWmO4uP7Yha2xNMV1m0zmjfqtZgsKmTA1Qghku3I0rekTJ51cH2XlXan4zUV5hjjEolRWjREOR7N9DD9sCvoQF2kr3EhI553RYIdwgivRtYJYH4g6oqVv2nrob3KbrLwd95MbNnzwmCqGNM20q0zgF8HUJjCxIfphNyVcwO_00001571329166
                                            [name] => ensemble 2
                                            [image] => fjO9sb3FUmDFhgWn49v1Io5Oa5sdFyL7KZRVzsH0n06n7GtNqIPdFSfDT67BSIvfYSmdTh7IoYyize3SDX169cas4MWMwVWLsF989ZWy76ANsYS4tkLS5OYR1i2TrqXjP40WDCcWvr6OkQapgzuk4hAISx7Mwf6Wp2Z3krzjn72PrTXUDmG7nDrp7VKDrsonCVqkmGs7lAwocdEeghWs7NUVkMdIGMjWDVo8u3wlClzs2e5X_00001571329177
                                            [produits] => 
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: I think we dont have the same driver !

Comment: Hi @OmarBerrami - updated my answer to include PHP specific examples.